# How to suppress specific compiler warnings in Xcode11

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-warnings, xcode11

I am using third party framework in my swift project with Xcode11, which is having many warnings for

> Non-portable path to file "HeaderFile.h"; Specified path differs in case from file name on disk Headerfile.h

Is there any way to suppress these specific warnings? or any way to silent framework warnings?

I went through with many threads but did't find the expected solution.

Any inputs would be a great help here, Thank you!!

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Updated question with exact warning.

Answer (score 1):

Add `-Wno-nonportable-include-path` to your compiler options.

In Xcode, click the “Show the Project navigator” icon at the top left (leftmost icon under the red-yellow-green window buttons) or select View > Navigators > Show Project Navigator.

The select the project (topmost item in the tree shown in the sidebar once the project navigator view is shown). To the right, click on Build Settings. Below that, and to the left, in Basic / Customized / All, click All.

Scroll to “Apple Clang - Custom Compiler Flags”. Click the blank field to the right of “Other Warning Flags”. A dialog with fields to enter options will pop up. Click “+” at the bottom left. In the empty field that becomes editable, enter “-Wno-nonportable-include-path”.

Comment: Yes this is the warning but where should I add `-Wno-nonportable-include-path` in compiler options?

Comment: @RJ168: I updated with instructions to add the switch to the `Other Warning Flags` options.

Comment: I have added the flag as per provided steps but still I can see same warnings in project.

Comment: @RJ168: It may be necessary to see your project in more detail than is feasible through Stack Overflow, to see why the flag is not getting applied during the build of whatever component is producing the failing error message. A workaround, of course, is to rename the file on disk to be what the source code expects it to be. Actually, given the purpose of the warning, that could be a fix rather than a workaround.